# how do i convert a list into a string

Tags: python, mysql-connector

i have tried to use the .replace or .strip method but have been unsuccessful with doing such. I am trying to print out a single stringed list separated by commas.

does anyone know a way to make it so it us printing out with no [] or single quotes ''

```
def get_format(header1):
    format_lookup = "SELECT ID, FormatName, HeaderRow, ColumnStatus, ColumnMobileID, ColumnVendorID, ColumnTechID, " \
                    "ColumnCallType, ColumnCallDate, ColumnCallTime, ColumnCallTo, ColumnQty, ColumnQtyLabel " \
                    "from dynamic_format WHERE HeaderRow=%s"
    
    header1 = (str(header1),)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(format_lookup, header1)
    record = cursor.fetchone()

    return record
```

Comment: Just so I understand, you have a list of strings, and you want to display it as a single string? How do you want the items to be separated? Can you provide an example of the exact output you want?

Comment: yes i want it displayed as a single string like such 'ESN, ORIGINAL_QUANTITY, INVOICE_DATE'

Comment: You should be able to do `", ".join(header1)`, if `header1` is indeed a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I'll post my comment as an answer:

```py
In [1]: header1 = ['ESN', 'ORIGINAL_QUANTITY', 'INVOICE_DATE']

In [2]: ", ".join(header1)
Out[2]: 'ESN, ORIGINAL_QUANTITY, INVOICE_DATE'

In [3]: print(", ".join(header1))
ESN, ORIGINAL_QUANTITY, INVOICE_DATE
```

The reason you're getting those errors is because `header1` is a `list` object and `.replace()` is a string method.

@sbabtizied's answer is what you'd use if `header1` was a string:

```py
# a single string, what sbabti assumed you had
"['ESN', 'ORIGINAL_QUANTITY', 'INVOICE_DATE']"

# a list of strings, what you actually have
['ESN', 'ORIGINAL_QUANTITY', 'INVOICE_DATE']
```